# BQ - How to merge two rows with json value into one row with the two values

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two rows as described in the picture link below and I need to merge them to one row that contains the data from both lines.
I try to do something as you can see in the attached picture link but I still don't succeed to get the expected result.
Any suggestions how I can do it in BigQuery/Sqlalchemy/MySql?

data for example (two rows):
sid data
123 {...}
123 {...}

The expected result (one row):
sid data
123 {'1': {...}, '2': {...}}

Thanks in advance!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EErNm.png

Comment: Please see [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/16019058)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help of string manipulation, following approach seems to be possible.

```
WITH table AS (
  SELECT 'S-1' sid, 'aaa' guid, 'CN=DESKTOP' dn, 'DESKTOP' name, 'DESKTOP' display_name UNION ALL
  SELECT 'S-1' sid, 'aaa' guid, 'CN=DESKTOP' dn, 'DESKTOP' name, 'DESKTOP' display_name UNION ALL
  SELECT 'S-2' sid, 'bbb' guid, 'CN=DESKTOP' dn, 'DESKTOP' name, 'DESKTOP' display_name UNION ALL
  SELECT 'S-2' sid, 'bbb' guid, 'CN=DESKTOP' dn, 'DESKTOP' name, 'DESKTOP' display_name 
)
SELECT sid, "{" || STRING_AGG(data) || "}" data FROM (
  SELECT sid, '"' || ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sid) || '": ' || TO_JSON_STRING(t) data 
    FROM table t
)
GROUP BY sid;
```

output:

[image]

or, if each **sid** has a same and fixed **sidcount**, you can use **pivot** to generate similar result like below.

```sql
SELECT sid, TO_JSON_STRING(STRUCT(_1, _2)) data 
  FROM (
    SELECT sid, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sid) AS rn, t AS data 
      FROM table t
  ) PIVOT (ANY_VALUE(data) FOR rn IN (1, 2));
```

[image]